# Variable holds the string "He", but "Hello World" gets printed

Tags: c, string, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
 char c[2];
      strcpy(c,"Hello World");
      printf("%s",c);
}
```

In the code above, I have initialized a character array which can hold only two characters. Then, the output of the above code must have been "He". But, I find that the output is "Hello World". How is this possible?

Debugging this program I find that until the execution of the printf statement, the value of c is indeed (as expected) "He". But right after printf is executed, the full text "Hello World" gets printed on the output screen!

The interesting part is c holds the string "He", but when we print out c, it prints "Hello World" !!

Can anyone please explain how is this happening?

Comment: This is undefined behavior; you're writing "Hello World" past the end of the array. C doesn't care about the length of the array (it also doesn't know about the length of the array), it only cares about where it finds a nullbyte, which is past the end.

Comment: Oh!! okay... @Aplet123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you are trying to access memory which is not valid in the context of your program.

The statement

```
 strcpy(c,"Hello World");
```

tries to copy a larger source to a smaller-sized destination, and since `strcpy()` does not do any check of the source length and the length of the supplied destination buffer, in attempt to copy, it access past the valid memory and access memory which is not allocated to your program.

**Result:** [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related, from the [man page for `strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

> *[...] The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.[...]*

and

> #### Bugs
>
> If the destination string of a strcpy() is not large enough, then anything might happen. Overflowing fixed-length string buffers is a favorite cracker technique for taking complete control of the machine. Any time a program reads or copies data into a buffer, the program first needs to check that there's enough space. This may be unnecessary if you can show that overflow is impossible, but be careful: programs can get changed over time, in ways that may make the impossible possible.

Answer (score 2):

The following statements invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB) by attempting to write to memory that the running program does not own.

```
char c[2];
strcpy(c,"Hello World");
```

The first statement creates two locations of `char` memory, but the string literal `"Hello World"` requires 12  minimum (including room for `\0`). Upon executing `strcpy(...)` anything can happen, even appearing to work, but as stated, it is invoking UB.

Declaring enough room for the intended use of a `char` array is essential and can be done many ways, for example, either of the following will work:

```
 char c[] = {"Hello World"};//let compiler do the work of determining size needed
 printf("%s", c);
```

Or:

```
 char c[12] = {0};//provide minimum of length of string + 1 for null termination.

 strcpy(c,"Hello World");
 printf("%s", c);
```

But if `c` is intended to be used to contain larger strings later in your program, then size it larger accordingly.